# how to add a variable value to a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

This is my function:
The problem is that I don't know how to add "value" to the "link".

```
   function add_subject_to_subjects_list() {
        var value = $("#id_name").val();
        var link = "/subject/create/"+value;
        show_subjects_list();
        $("#btn-create-subject").click(function() {
            $.post(link, function(data) {
                show_subjects_list();
                alert(data).hide("fast");
            });
        });
    }
```

Because of that my function post data to the different link: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/subject/create/`

But I want my link depends on value:
and it should look like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/subject/create/some_value/
```

that's the whole js for that page:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    add_subject_to_subjects_list();
});

function show_subjects_list() {
    $.post("/subject/list/", function(data){
        for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            $("#list").append('<li>'+data[i]['fields']['name']+'</li><br>');
        };
    }, 'json');
}

function add_subject_to_subjects_list() {
    var value = $("#id_name").val();
    var link = "/subject/create/"+value;
    show_subjects_list();
    $("#btn-create-subject").click(function() {
        $.post(link, function(data) {
            show_subjects_list();
            alert(data).hide("fast");
        });
    });
}
```

that's my server-side (I'm using Django/Python):

```
@csrf_exempt
def subjects_list(request):
    user = request.user
    subjects = Subjects.objects.filter(user__exact = user)
    result = serializers.serialize("json", subjects, fields=('name'))
    return HttpResponse(result)

@csrf_exempt
def new_subject(request, subject):
    subject, created= Subjects.objects.get_or_create( 
        name=subject,
        user=request.user,
        created_by=request.user)
    if created:
        message = "Subject was created"
    else:
        message = "No subject was added to the database"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

and that's my html:

```
{% block left-menu %}

    <div class="sidebar">
        <h3>Subjects</h3>
        <p> Enter subject name to add </p>
        <br>

        <div id="create-subject">
            <form method="post" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
                {{ subject_creation_form.as_p }}
                <input type="button" value="Create Subject" id="btn-create-subject" />
            </form>
        </div>

            <div id="subjects-list">
                <a id="append">myID</a>
                <ul id="list">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

that's the form for that html:

```
class SubjectCreationForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Subject Name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':9}))

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('created_by', 'created_time', 'num_of_followers', 'vote')
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if len(name)>1:
            return name
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Subject name should be longer")
```

Comment: Can you post some more code, specifically where the function is called and the field $("#id_name")

Comment: It just looks like value is empty, also alert doesn't return a jQuery object

Comment: I don't see an element with id `id_name`

Comment: @Musa, this is not an issue, because Django automatically created id based on forms names... if I will look at "View Source" I would find it in a right place.

Comment: and server-side works fine, because if i manually type http://127.0.0.1:8000/subject/create/some_value, it will display message and create an object in database.

Comment: If the idea is to use the value of the "#id_name" field at the time the "#btn-create-subject" click event occurs then you need to move the first two lines of `add_subject_to_subjects_list()` _inside_ the `.click()` handler. Otherwise you're always using whatever the value of "#id_name" was when the page first loaded.

Comment: Thank you everybody! now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @nnnnnn suggested, first two line of code had to be placed inside $.post like that:

```
......
$("#btn-create-subject").click(function() {
        var value = $("#id_name").val();
        var link = "/subject/create/"+value;
        $.post(link, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
.......
```

Thank to everybody)

Answer (score 1):

The click handler is attached on page load and uses the value of `id_name` that time, which I assume is empty, use the value of `id_name` when the button is clicked.

```
function add_subject_to_subjects_list() {
    show_subjects_list();
    $("#btn-create-subject").click(function() {
        $.post("/subject/create/"+$("#id_name").val(), function(data) {
            show_subjects_list();
            alert(data);//.hide("fast");
        });
    });
}
```

Also do the same for `show_subjects_list`